# Why does ==~ not match correct regular expression in Groovy?

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy

```
def pattern = ~"development";
def string = "game-development";
if (string ==~ pattern) {
    println("happy")
} else {
    println("sad")
}
```

**Why does this code not match and produce "sad" in the result?** 
As far as I know (and I checked this with [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/52QzM7/1), just to be sure) it should match, but it doesn't.

I've found the workaround:

```
def pattern = ~(".*?" + "development" + ".*?");
```

but it doesn't look amazing + if I ever wanted to use the matches I would need to capture "development" in the group, because it matches the entire string now.

Comment: Groovy is written on top of Java, any problems that arrive there, are often corelated to Java/are Java problems, so it might not be Groovy, but Java problem.

Comment: from the [tag:java] tag description: "*Use this tag when you're having problems using or understanding the **language itself**.*" (emphasis added)  -- which is not the case here -- in Java you would do `Pattern.compile("development").matcher(string).find()` or even `string.contains("development")` (can't see how that would help) -- maybe the [tag:regex] tag would be more recommended

Comment: @user85421 I'm not sure if the tag still don't include this question, but I deleted the tag. (edit, thanks for additional explanation)